# Run Azure DevOps CI Pipeline with Scheduler and Variable Group

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml

We have one pipeline and one only (we cannot and do not want to create a 2nd pipeline or do it with a separate pipeline, it has to be done in the same pipeline), that pipeline has a task to either stop or start a function while accepting a variable group (its required) from the library (we specify those store A-E variables on the YAML but they also exist in the library), and specify the Azure subscription. Currently, we run this pipeline manually, this is what it looks like before I run it

[image]

What I'm looking for is a feature to automate this pipeline to run at 7 PM CST with the **start** function as the task, accept a variable group, and specify which azure subscription that i want. Then, at 6 AM CST the next day, I need to have that SAME pipeline to run a build with **stop** function as the task, accept a variable group, and specify which azure subscription i want.
I found a scheduler feature in the CI pipeline but it doesnt allow me to specify which variable group I want from the library, no option to select either start or stop the function, and no option to select the subscription. This is what I'm expecting to see

[image]

If it any helps this is the .YAML code that i have (some stuff has been removed for privacy purposes)

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

parameters:
- name: variableGroup
  displayName: Variable Group
  type: string
  values:
  - 'variable for store A'
  - 'variable for store B'
  - 'variable for store C'
  - 'variable for store D'
  - 'variable for store E'
    
- name: artifactVersion
  displayName: ArtifactVersion (* (latest) or 1.{sprintNumber}.{ReleaseNo})
  type: string
  default: '*'

- name: Function
  displayName: Function
  type: string
  default: 'deploy'
  values:
  - deploy  
  
- name: task
  displayName: ExecuteTask
  type: string
  default: ''
  values:
  - start thefunction
  - stop the function
  
- name: Subscription
  displayName: Subscription
  type: string 
  values:
  - 'sandbox'
  - 'production '
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that there is no such method can meet your requirements for the time being.

Refer to this doc: [Scheduled triggers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sl5lP.png)

```
schedules:
- cron: string # cron syntax defining a schedule
  displayName: string # friendly name given to a specific schedule
  branches:
    include: [ string ] # which branches the schedule applies to
    exclude: [ string ] # which branches to exclude from the schedule
  always: boolean # whether to always run the pipeline or only if there have been source code changes since the last successful scheduled run. The default is false.
```

The Schedule trigger does not support setting the target value for Parameters.

On the other hand, when you set the runtime parameters, the option or drop-down list to select the value can only be displayed when the pipeline is run manually.

I can fully understand your requirements.

You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions:

[image]

Comment: okay Kevin, thank you, ill submit it there, appreciate for the feedback

Comment: @JackRogers. Can you share the suggestion ticket link here? I will help vote it.

Comment: here is the link https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Run-Azure-DevOps-CI-Pipeline-with-Schedu/1528032?space=21&entry=myfeedback, thank you for voting and working it, appreciate for the help and attention