# Turn On Function (Resource) at a Specific Time of The Day

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We have over 20 functions inside one function in each environment and yes I'm aware of the timer trigger. What I'm looking for is a way to turn on the azure function resource itself (not the functions inside the function) at a specific time of the day, and turn off the azure function resource itself at a specific time of the day.

We tried looking for a way to do this in through azure devops CI pipeline (which is usually how we turn on and off the azure function resource itself) as you can see here but its [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69124474/run-azure-devops-ci-pipeline-with-scheduler-and-variable-group/69126686?noredirect=1#comment122232417_69126686) yet supported atm

Comment: I believe you can get your required output via setting cronjobs on your server.

Comment: @groovy_guy our function doesnt have a server, it has an appservice though, is there a way to configure it from the azure function/appservice resource themselves?

Comment: Describe "on"? What do you mean? Are you trying to save money? Have you looked into [consumption plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/consumption-plan)? or do you want the functions to not be available for other reasons?

Comment: theres a button that says "(arrow icon) Start" if you open an azure function resource on azure portal page, thats the button that i meant. Why we are doing this? No we arent saving money bud, we cant do this manually in prod environment, the function resource must be on and off in a specific time on the day and in production we have to use a CI pipeline, we cant do it manually, it was designed that way and not up for a debate, this question is only applicable in the test env and i just wanted to know if my question is even doable

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Azure App Service Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureappservice/#actions) within a Logic App to [Create schedule-based and recurring automation workflows with Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/tutorial-build-schedule-recurring-logic-app-workflow).

These actions can also (re)start or stop an Azure Function App.

The example in the screenshot runs once every day at 12:00 and starts the Function App called `gtmooaf01`.

[image: Example Logic App]